# Need minor help in react redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I have been able to set up basic react redux for counter application but due to some issues (no warning, no error), I am not able to read the default counter state in the component.

Code:

```
const initialState = {counter:0}
const incrementReducer = (state = initialState, action)=> {
const {type, payload} = action;

  if (type == 'INCREMENT') {
    return {...state, counter:state.counter + 1 };
  }
return state;
}

const decrementReducer = (state = initialState, action)=> {
const {type, payload} = action;

  if (type == 'DECREMENT') {
    return {...state, counter:state.counter - 1 };
  }
return state;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({incrementReducer, decrementReducer});
  const store = createStore(rootReducer);
    // const store = createStore(incrementReducer);



function Counter() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  console.log({counter});
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => dispatch({'type':'INCREMENT'})}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        {counter}
      </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store = {store}>
    <Counter/>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Here is the link to the code to run it:
https://snack.expo.dev/@iosdose/react-redux-counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code

```js
combineReducers({incrementReducer, decrementReducer})
```

lets you end up with a state that has the shape:

```js
{
  incrementReducer: counter,
  decrementReducer: counter
}
```

As you see, it doesn't make any sense to split that up into two reducers, as one value can only go up and the other value can only go down now.

Generally, you are following an extremely outdated style of Redux here, so I would highly recommend that you follow [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) to learn modern Redux instead.
Modern Redux (since 2019) does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable update logic, `createStore/combineReducers` and the likes. It is less code and easier to read and write.
You can see a very short introduction to modern Redux [here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today), but I would really recommend you to go with the above tutorial.

I would also recommed you to follow this in a normal React applicaton first to get a feeling for it, instead of using React native, as you can use the Redux devtools browser extension there.